# What qualifications are required to become chief instructor at a 141 flight school (FAA)?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, cfi

Under the FAA jurisdiction flight school operations can be conducted under the provisions of part 61 or part 141. If a flight instructor wanted to become a chief instructor at a part 141 flight school, what would they need to be qualified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are in [14 CFR 141.35](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=193036e5e57cba2af1a052c85a8415dd&mc=true&node=pt14.3.141&rgn=div5#se14.3.141_135), *Chief instructor qualifications*. They're too long to quote here in full and the exact requirements depend on the type of instruction, but in summary:

- Hold a commercial or ATP certificate
- Hold a CFI certificate
- Pass knowledge and proficiency tests
- Meet minimum flight time requirements (depending on the type of instruction, e.g. 1000 hrs PIC time is required for private pilot instruction)
- Meet minimum flight training time requirements

For training pilots for an instrument rating, the chief instructor also needs an instrument rating, instrument flight time and instrument training experience.